# align two div in same line while screen size less than 768 px or smaller

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a footer container. There are some menu items and two paddels(left and right) to scroll left and right the menu. There are one description text and one log link.

Now, if the screen size is more than 768px then all these three divs( menu, description text, log link) are in same line. Which is fine. But, if i choose screen size less than <768px then as per my application design will be like this below.

```
    <  Menu >
Description text     Log link
```

Here is the screenshot for less than <768 px.
[image: Current condition]

Now, description text and log link aren't in same line . Because of repair log width, menu inner wrapper is hided behind the screen. How to solve this?

Here is my css style for less than (768 px screen)

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 414px)  and (max-width: 767px) {
  .footerContainer {
    height: 72px;
    flex-direction: column;
    .menu_item_outer_wrapper {
      width: 390px !important;
      height: 100%;
      .paddles {
        display: block;
        .left-paddle {
          transform: translate(-1%, -45%);
        }
        .right-paddle {
          right:0;
          transform: translate(10%, -45%);
        }
      }
      .menu_item_inner_wrapper {
        margin-left: 36px;
      }
    }
    .footer-desc_log-section {
      width: 100%;
      .footer__description {
        width: 60%;
        margin-left: 8px;
      }
      .footer__description,
      .footer__audit-log {
        line-height: 32px;
      }
    }
    .footer-desc_log-section {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  div{
    display:inline;
  }
}
.div2{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div1">Div 1</div>
  <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
<body/>
```

You can check out this code just add `display:inline;` in the CSS of the div.